# U2F Key with NFC and USB-C

Tags: security

Are there any commercially available U2F keys that support both USB-C and NFC?

So far I've looked at [Yubico](https://www.yubico.com/store/) which seems to have a USB-C model that doesn't have NFC support or a USB-A model that does support NFC.

I've also found the [SoloKeys](https://solokeys.com/preorder/) site which seems to be what I'm looking for but they aren't yet available for purchase.